# How to use the Rules module to attribute a new user role after a product was bought?

Tags: 7, commerce, rules, users

I use these modules: [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [Node option premium](https://www.drupal.org/project/nopremium).

My question: with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), how attribute a new user role, when the product was bought, and when this product is a premium content ? So that, when a user bought the product, that user can have access to full content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the tutorial [Selling Content with Drupal Commerce using Content Access and Roles](http://commerceguys.com/blog/selling-content-drupal-commerce-using-content-access-and-roles) for granting access to premium content to users who have a "premium" role.

Here is a summary of the steps required (= quote from that link):

- Enable [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) and the ACL (optional) module.
- Create a role called "premium".
- Create a content type called "Premium Content" and put some great content in it.
- Verify that users can only access the premium content if they have the premium role.
- Create a product representing the premium role.
- Create a rule that grants the premium role on order completion:

  - After updating an order.
  - If the order state is Completed.
  - And the order contains our premium product.
  - Add a role to the user who is the owner of the order.